# Getting data from only one table on multiple table joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, stream

I have written a MySQL query for social networking stream.

Here it is:

```
SELECT distinct(d.id), d.directory, u.name, u.pic
FROM data as d, follow as f, users as u  
WHERE f.flwid = $id 
  AND f.status = 1 
  AND d.blocked = '0'
  AND (d.upld_id = $id OR d.timeline_id = $id OR d.upld_id = f.acid OR d.timeline_id = f.acid)
  AND (d.`with`<if(f.is_con=1,3,2) or d.`with`<if(d.upld_id=$id,4,2)) 
  AND u.id = d.upld_id 
ORDER BY 
    d.id DESC 
LIMIT 18
```

Now the problem above is that when user doesn't follow anyone (i.e follow table doesn't have any rows for a specific user) it doesn't show user's own post in home stream because both table doesn't join because of no rows in follow table.

I can't configure how I can change this query I just use follow table's corredentials 4-5 places and i cant use `IN` with subquery because for subqueries will overburden the server :)

Anyone help please It will be appreciated very much.

**Currently it gives data like this**
If user have followed one or more peoples/pages 
Than it shows user's own and followed account's posts.

**But ** if user doesn't follow any other account means a newly registered user than he/she share any post it doesn't show in home stream because the follow table doesn't join with other two tables because it doesn't have any rows for session user.

**Edit**
The Above SQL query returns the rows which contains unique post by user and his followings.
I show these posts in home of users's account with the help of PHP .
But the problem i getting is that When user is new or he/she doesn't follow  someone than than the follow table doesn't join with data table thats why users's own posts also not shown up in her/his account's home. Someone help me in solving my SQL query.
I have found just a Non-SQL idea in which in users table i will store a column named `n_followings`  and at the time of fetching data with query i will use PHP condition and if n_followings==0 than  i will use this sql query

```
SELECT <columns> FROM data where timeline_id='$;id' or upld_id='$id'
```

Comment: FYI, `DISTINCT` is not a function, it doesn't take an argument like that. It's a keyword that applies to the entire `SELECT` list.

Comment: please provide data and results that you want to get. It is close to impossible to figure out what exactly you are asking.

Comment: i edited again........................................ :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT d.id, d.directory, u.name, u.pic
FROM data AS d
JOIN users AS u ON u.id = d.upld_id
LEFT JOIN follow AS f 
ON f.flwid = $id 
    AND f.status = 1 
    AND (d.upld_id = $id OR d.timeline_id = $id OR d.upld_id = f.acid OR d.timeline_id = f.acid)
WHERE d.`with` < IF(f.is_con = 1, 3, 2)
    OR d.`with` < IF(d.upld_id = $id, 4, 2)
ORDER BY d.id DESC
LIMIT 18
```

Comment: i have checked it and it only shows last 18 rows of data table .
Again I want To tell that i want to show Home Stream(DATA) thats why tose condition are they are not for just joining tables.................hope you will again edit your answer thankyou i appreciate you

Comment: I just copied `LIMIT 18` from your original query, that's why it only shows the last 18 rows.

Comment: but its ok that it shows 18 rows but the problem is that it shows them from all users criteriz doesn't apply on data table :)

Comment: Please update your question. Post some sample data, and the result you're hoping to get.

Comment: i allready edited :- see this
Currently it gives data like this If user have followed one or more peoples/pages Than it shows user's own and followed account's posts.

**But ** if user doesn't follow any other account means a newly registered user than he/she share any post it doesn't show in home stream because the follow table doesn't join with other two tables because it doesn't have any rows for session user.

Comment: You haven't edited it as I need. I asked you to post some sample data and the desired results. Not a description, the actual rows of input and output that you want.